# Can a tag wiki have multiple definitions?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, tag-wiki

Noob question, but I was wondering if a tag wiki can have multiple definitions if it is a broad tag.

Just as an example, I was looking at [direction](/questions/tagged/direction), which has two meanings both in computer software and computer graphics (directing a function, and then the physical direction of a graphic).

I was going to edit, "In computer software ... {explanation} ... In computer graphics ... {explanation} ..." But I'm not sure if it will get rejected because it has multiple definitions.

Comment: @Martjin_Pieters Okay... And yeah, I agree, it really was a broad tag. Just got bored so I started editing tags. :)

Comment: Yeah, that's a terrible tag.  You know it's a terrible tag, because nobody would ever follow it or look through the list of questions tagged with it.

Comment: I had a similar [question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/169959/212576) about [tag:table].

Comment: @BackinaFlash: Well, table really means only one thing.  Granted, you can have different kinds of tables, but you can also have more than one tag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That *specific* tag should not exist. It is a [meta tag in need of burning](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135985).

But generally speaking, for tags that can and should exist, needing two different explanations is indicative of a tag that should be split instead. Create a *new*, more specific tag for at least one of the two subjects, and start retagging. Request help here on Meta if there are a lot of questions needing retagging.